# Finding paths in an adjacency list

Tags: algorithm

What is the optimal algorithm to find all the paths between 2 nodes of an adjacency list

Example input:

```
source = 1
destination = 5
list = {1: [2], 2: [4], 3: [4, 5], 4: [5]}
```

Comment: Did you try any line of code you want to share?

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We need to see the minimal code in the question that demonstrates the problem you're having. As is you're asking us to write that code, convert it from Java, or to find it for you, all of which are off-topic. Also, there's a homework smell to the question, so be sure to read the link in [ask] about homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def paths(adj, st, en)
  return [] unless adj.key?(st)
  adj[st].each_with_object([]) do |nxt,arr|
    nxt == en ? arr << [st, en] :
      paths(adj, nxt, en).each { |a| arr << [st, *a] }
  end
end
```

```
adj = { 1=>[2,3], 2=>[4,7], 3=>[4,8], 4=>[5,6], 5=>[7], 6=>[7] }
```

Note that I added an isolated node `8`.

```
paths(adj, 1, 7)
  #=> [[1, 2, 4, 5, 7],
  #    [1, 2, 4, 6, 7],
  #    [1, 2, 7],
  #    [1, 3, 4, 5, 7],
  #    [1, 3, 4, 6, 7]]
```